# Bulkified trigger giving error on data import: Z4PAccountAddressTrigger: System.LimitException: Too many future calls: 51

Tags: apex, trigger, callout, data-loader, future

I have a future call that gives me the error: System.LimitException: Too many future calls: 51, while importing multiple record with data loader. I did some googling on the limitations of future calls and it seems best practice would be to use Queueable apex. I have seen an example of salesforce but not sure how to implement this in my case. Below is my future call.

Apex

```
public class AccountAddressUpdate 
{
    @future
    public static void AddressUpdate(Set<id> setId) 
    {
        List<te_Account_Address__c> listteAccountAddress =[SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Account__c, te_Address__r.Street__c, te_Address__r.Postal_Code__c,te_Address__r.City__c, te_Address__r.Country__r.name, 
                                                            te_Address__r.Housenumber__c, te_Address__r.Housenumber_Extension__c, Address_Type__c FROM te_Account_Address__c WHERE id IN :setId]; 
        if (setId.size() != null) {
            List<Account> accUpdAddressBilling = new List<Account> ();
            List<Account> accUpdAddressShipping = new List<Account> ();
            List<Account> accUpdAddressMailing = new List<Account> ();
            for (te_Account_Address__c ac : listteAccountAddress) {
                // add account to list to be updated
                if (ac.Address_Type__c  == 'Billing') {
                    Account acc = new Account(Id = ac.Account__c,
                                              BillingStreet = ac.te_Address__r.Street__c,
                                              BillingPostalCode = ac.te_Address__r.Postal_Code__c,
                                              BillingCity = ac.te_Address__r.City__c,
                                              BillingCountry = ac.te_Address__r.Country__r.name,
                                              Billing_Housenumber__c = ac.te_Address__r.Housenumber__c,
                                              Billing_Housenumber_Extension__c = ac.te_Address__r.Housenumber_Extension__c
                                             );
                    accUpdAddressBilling.add(acc);system.debug(acc);
                }
                if (ac.Address_Type__c  == 'shipping') {
                    Account acc = new Account(Id = ac.Account__c,
                                              ShippingStreet = ac.te_Address__r.Street__c,
                                              ShippingPostalCode = ac.te_Address__r.Postal_Code__c,
                                              ShippingCity = ac.te_Address__r.City__c,
                                              ShippingCountry = ac.te_Address__r.Country__r.name,
                                              Shipping_Housenumber__c = ac.te_Address__r.Housenumber__c,
                                              Shipping_Housenumber_Extension__c = ac.te_Address__r.Housenumber_Extension__c
                                             );
                    accUpdAddressShipping.add(acc);system.debug('Shipping done');
                }
                if (ac.Address_Type__c == 'mailing') {
                    Account acc = new Account(Id = ac.Account__c,
                                              PersonMailingStreet = ac.te_Address__r.Street__c,
                                              PersonMailingPostalCode = ac.te_Address__r.Postal_Code__c,
                                              PersonMailingCity = ac.te_Address__r.City__c,
                                              PersonMailingCountry = ac.te_Address__r.Country__r.name
                                             );
                    accUpdAddressMailing.add(acc);
                }
            }
            update accUpdAddressBilling;
            update accUpdAddressShipping;
            update accUpdAddressMailing;
        }
    }
}
```

Triggerhandler

```
public with sharing class teAccountAddressTriggerHandler {

    private boolean isExecuting = false;

    public teAccountAddressTriggerHandler(){
        // do something
    }

    public void OnBeforeInsert(List<te_Account_Address__c> newteAccountAddress){
        //EXECUTE BEFORE INSERT LOGIC
    }

    public void OnAfterInsert(List<te_Account_Address__c> newteAccountAddress){
            teAccountAddressSet(newteAccountAddress);
    }

    public void OnBeforeUpdate(List<te_Account_Address__c> oldteAccountAddress, List<te_Account_Address__c> updatedteAccountAddress, Map<Id, te_Account_Address__c> teAccountAddressMap){
        //BEFORE UPDATE LOGIC
    }

    public void OnAfterUpdate(List<te_Account_Address__c> oldteAccountAddress, List<te_Account_Address__c> updatedteAccountAddress, Map<Id, te_Account_Address__c> teAccountAddressMap){
        //AFTER UPDATE LOGIC
     teAccountAddressSet(updatedteAccountAddress);
    }
    /*
public void OnBeforeDelete(List<Lead> LeadsToDelete, Map<Id, Lead> LeadMap){
//BEFORE DELETE LOGIC
}

public void OnAfterDelete(List<Lead> deletedLeads, Map<Id, Lead> LeadMap){
//AFTER DELETE LOGIC
}

public void OnUndelete(List<Lead> restoredLeads){
//AFTER UNDELETE LOGIC
}

public boolean IsTriggerContext{
get{ return isExecuting;}
}*/
    public static void teAccountAddressSet(List<te_Account_Address__c> updatedteAccountAddress){
            Set<Id> Ids = new Set<Id>();
             for (te_Account_Address__c Aa : updatedteAccountAddress){
            if(Aa.Start_Date__c == system.today()){
                Ids.add(Aa.Id);
            }
            AccountAddressUpdate.AddressUpdate(Ids);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: where and how do you call this `AddressUpdate` method?

Comment: @Novarg I added the part where I call the method

Comment: ```Maximum number of Apex jobs added to the queue with System.enqueueJob = 50``` queue will not help you in this case either, because it has same limits https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

Comment: 1) what is the batch size of your data loader input; 2) are you sure there is no recursion?

Comment: @cropredy There are 241 records

Comment: change your data loader settings to make the batch size small (like 10)